# Why is jQuery not working in Angular 1 and Angular 2?

Tags: jquery

jQuery is not working in Angular 1 and Angular 2. I am just trying to put simple jQuery function hide and show. I am using Angular 1.5 and jQuery 3.2

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

$('documment').ready(function(){
   $('#mydiv').hide();
   $('#mydiv1').click(function(){
       $('#mydiv').show();
   });
});
```

Comment: Do you see any error on console? You also had a missing **'** after **#mydiv1**

Comment: Why do you need jQuery?

Comment: There's not enough information to go on here. Are you including jquery? Are you including it before angular? Are you using versions of jquery which are supported by angular? Where did you add the above code?

Comment: i have order properly Angular and jquery

Comment: but its not working

Comment: I would recommend you not to use jquery, you can achieve all of those effects using just angular. And you should user either angular1, or angular2 or jquery

Comment: but if i want to use somehwere jquery in angualr then some parts...because i feel that things happen easily in jquery not angular ...please help me out i am new to on angualrjs

Answer (score 0):

You had a syntax error, you were missing a **'** character in `$('#mydiv1)`

However if you are getting an error like,

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Make sure you have included Angular and jQuery in a proper order.

Like below,

```
<!-- Add jQuery first -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<!-- And then AngularJS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularjs.js"></script>
```

Comment: jquery come first and then angular come second

Comment: i am not getting any error of this kind ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: i tried with proper order of file but though also its not working

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mydiv').hide();
    $('#mydiv1').click(function(){
        // Empty.
    });
});
```